# how to get last week count using sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a sql query to get last week's count in the format of mm/count/yyyy. In my situation, Wednesday starts a new week. So today March 8th, 2012 is the second week of March, and the last week count is 03/01/2012. Please note, the 01 means week count not date. If consider March 1st, 2012, the last week count should be the last week of Feburary which is 02/05/2012

Update: Thanks for Steve's comment, reminding me to clear my question here. Each month starts from it's first Wednesday. So the 03/01/2012 starts from March 7th, 2012 to March 13th, 2012

Any sql query solution?

I'm using sql-server

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Some have built-in functions to get week numbers...

Comment: The OP does not want week number, he want to count number of Wednesday since the beginning of the month.

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel The week number can be used to determine the previous week, and some APIs allow you to select the day which starts the week - i.e Wednesday.

Comment: Do you have a numbers table at your disposal?

Comment: Wow. 135 questions asked, 6 votes cast.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx together with  [`SET DATEFIRST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) Sorry I don't have time to craft and test a solution right now...

Answer (score 2):

Here's some date logic to get you started.  I can't comprehend your funky "last week count" definition by the two examples, so I can't code it.

```
DECLARE
  @Now datetime,
  @Today datetime,
  @MonthStart datetime,
  @WeekCount int,
  @Result varchar(10)

SET @Now = GetDate()
SET @Today = DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, @Now), 0)
SET @MonthStart = DateAdd(mm, DateDiff(mm, 0, @Today), 0)

  -- relative to the actual day the month started
SET @WeekCount = ((DatePart(dd, @Today)-1) / 7) + 1

  -- relative to Sunday
--SET @WeekCount = (DatePart(week, @Today) - (DatePart(week, @MonthStart) + 1

SET @Result = convert(varchar(10), @Today, 101)
SET @Result =
  LEFT(@Result, 3) -- month/
  + RIGHT('z00' + convert(varchar(2), @WeekCount), 2) -- week with zero pad
  + RIGHT(@Result, 5) -- /year

SELECT
  @Now as TheNow,
  @Today as Today,
  @MonthStart as MonthStart,
  @WeekCount as WeekCount,
  @Result as Result
```

---

See also [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

Comment: For the curious, the z in the string literal prevents tsql from converting it to an int literal and then using integer addition.

Comment: The 'z' is unnecessary. It's the quotation marks that are important. SQL Server will not convert either operand of [quoted string literal] + [typed string] to an integer. In any case, SQL Server, as a strongly typed language, will make its decisions about casting operands within mixed-type expressions based on the types and the operators, not on the actual values. In any situation where '00' would be converted to an integer, using 'z00' instead would result in an error. (Another solution is right(100+@WeekCount,2).)

Answer (score 1):

in oracle:

```
select to_char( sysdate, 'w' ) from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

@Steven,

Sorry, this didn't fit as a comment.

Your description of "[nth] week in [month]" is not clear. Your week starts on Wednesday. February first was a Wednesday, so the weeks in February, 2012, if there are indeed 5 of them, are

1. February 1-7
2. February 8-14
3. February 15-21
4. February 22-28 and
5. February 29 - March 6

You describe March 8 as being in the "second week of March," so the first week of March must be the previous week, which is February 29 - March 6. Note that this is also what you call "the last (fifth) week in February."

By your description, then, the weeks you write as '02/05/2012' and '03/01/2012' are **the same week** with different names.

What is the rule that lets you know that

1. You want the same "last week" when you run the program March 1 as when you run it March 8
2. You want that week (which is the same) described differently in these two cases.

Or does your question have a mistake in it.

Once you can describe what you need, it will be easy to program. If you don't know what you want, it will be impossible to program.

Comment: 02/05/2012 and 03/01/2012 are not the same week. 02/05/2012 means date from Feb 29th to Mar 6th. 03/01/2012 means date from Mar 7th to Mar 13th. Each month starts from it's first Wednesday.

Comment: @Steven: Can you explain why you wrote in your question that "March 8th, 2012 is the second week of March"? You want the result when this is run on March 8 to be the week March 7 - March 13, then? I wouldn't describe that as "last week's count", which is how you put it.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server these queries return 1,1,2,5

```
select ((DATEPART(dd, 'March 01, 2012')-1)/7) + 1
select ((DATEPART(dd, 'March 07, 2012')-1)/7) + 1
select ((DATEPART(dd, 'March 08, 2012')-1)/7) + 1
select ((DATEPART(dd, 'March 31, 2012')-1)/7) + 1
```

So this may be what you need

```
declare @dt datetime = 'March 31, 2012'
select 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(4), DATEPART(month,@dt)) + '/' +
    CONVERT(nvarchar(4), ((DATEPART(dd, @dt)-1)/7) + 1) + '/' +
    CONVERT(nvarchar(4), DATEPART(year,@dt))
```

which produces '3/5/2012'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  RIGHT(100 + MONTH(D)        , 2) + '/' +
  RIGHT(100 + (DAY(D) + 6) / 7, 2) + '/' +
  DATENAME(YEAR, D)
FROM (
  SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()) AS D
) s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should do it, I don't get the value for last week because it was confusing and the answer is cleaner that way, you can just add a `DATEADD(day,-7,date)` somewhere.

```
SET DATEFORMAT YDM
CREATE TABLE #Dates (Date DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES ('2012-31-03');
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES ('2012-15-02');
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES ('2012-02-04');
INSERT INTO #Dates VALUES ('2012-02-05');

WITH Mondays as (
SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0, DATEADD(day,6-DATEPART(day,d.Date),d.Date) ), 0) FirstMonday,
       DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0, DATEADD(day,6-DATEPART(day,DATEADD(month, -1, d.Date)),DATEADD(month, -1, d.Date)) ), 0) FirstMondayOfLastMonth,
       d.Date
FROM #Dates d),
Wednesday as (
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,m.FirstMonday) <= 5 
            THEN DATEADD(day,2,m.FirstMonday) 
            ELSE DATEADD(day,-5,m.FirstMonday)  END FirstWednesday,
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,m.FirstMondayOfLastMonth) <= 5 
            THEN DATEADD(day,2,m.FirstMondayOfLastMonth) 
            ELSE DATEADD(day,-5,m.FirstMondayOfLastMonth)  END FirstWednesdayOfLastMonth,
       m.Date
FROM Mondays m)
SELECT w.Date,
       CASE WHEN w.Date >= w.FirstWednesday THEN
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month,w.Date) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2)
            + '/0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(week,w.FirstWednesday, w.Date) + 1 AS NVARCHAR(2)) 
            + '/' +  CAST(DATEPART(year,w.Date) AS NVARCHAR(4))
       ELSE
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month,w.FirstWednesdayOfLastMonth) AS NVARCHAR(2)),2)
            + '/0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(week,w.FirstWednesdayOfLastMonth, w.Date) + 1 AS NVARCHAR(2)) 
            + '/' +  CAST(DATEPART(year,w.FirstWednesdayOfLastMonth) AS NVARCHAR(4))
       END  AS weekDate
FROM Wednesday w

DROP TABLE #Dates
```

The result is :
Date    weekDate

2012-03-31 00:00:00.000 03/04/2012

2012-02-15 00:00:00.000 02/03/2012

2012-04-02 00:00:00.000 03/05/2012

2012-05-02 00:00:00.000 05/01/2012